# Known Chrome/Chromium themes that match popular themes

Tags: themes, google-chrome, chromium

Searching for themes for Chromium I found this: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/03/6-google-chrome-ubuntu-themes-radiance-ambiance-elementary-dust-etc/

Can you guys point to some other Chrome/Chromium themes that fit popular themes?

Here are some themes I like, but could not find fitting Chromium themes for:
Minty-Freshness
Victory
Hope
The Equinox pack

Others are welcome as well. Share plenty!

(For some reason, the OMG U comment section in the link is off. I bet there were a bunch of comments on this one :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ppnoicajnfbofmhbapnojgdbhdnnlohd) is a theme in the Chrome web store that is *similar* to Minty-Freshness, but doesn't quite match. I didn't see anything similar to Victory Hope.

But, [here is the web developer guide to making Chrome themes](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ThemeCreationGuide) and [this is an online tool to help create Chrome themes.](http://www.chrometheme.net/chrome-theme-creator-online.html)

Answer (score 1):

Chromium/Chrome is not perfect as far as gui integration goes but there are a few workarounds.

If you go to Preferences >> Personal, under Appearance you can select "Use GTK theme" and "Use system titlebar and borders".

Now, not always the system titlebar and borders will match chromium's ui (and you use extra space doing this) so I personally use it hidden. I stick to GTK for the icons and colors that match orta.

Equinox (Dawn) seems to have a little issue with the GTK theme as, while it does match and look nice, the icons are that of Faenza-Dark against a light background. You could change those specific icons in the /usr/share/icons/Faenza-dark folder. Not ideal but it works.

The other 3 Equinox gnome themes seem to work fine out of the box with this method.

There are extensions to achieve scrollbars that match your taste/you theme.

Elementary Scrollbar: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kglninkafjojambbaogionamfcelppil

Elementary Theme: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdongokkdiclimbompodchjpdglpfemg )

Simple Bar (Orta-esque scroll):
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lagmbbmdlgjncefjognkcadapmmkmphe

Adwaita Scrollbar:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bkgmaggeefkcgmhmgiadbhgdoeiajccd

There is also a theme for Divergence III (althought Divergence is already at IV).
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fejliiokfekdkmfjoeggpkdlndgbcopj

And for Shiki:
(White) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imbkdgihphehomdldnjomialcnehgnih

There are bound to be a few more similars one but my honest advice is to go with GTK if you can't find the specific theme for your setup. :)

Disclaimer: my ubuntu is in portuguese, forgive me if anything is incorrectly named - should be close enough.